# Any FTP software that requires administrator approval prior to uploading?

Tags: ftp

I am in search of FTP uploader software which provides me the features like:

1. Only admin will have the access right to upload the files.
2. If other users wants to upload then they should send the mail to Admin saying which file, which project, what is the update and why he needs to upload.
3. This is simply to keep track to loading the files in my FTP Server.

I use FileZilla in which I am unable to get these options. So can any one help me out to find any software which would satisfy my requirements. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking about enforcing *server* policy through the *client*. This is simply wrong. You should not trust your users for something like this.

The FTP protocol does not have any support for something like this anyway - and for good reason:

(1) You should configure your FTP server software so that only select accounts (the administrators) have write permissions, while everybody else has read-only permissions.

(2) What does this have to do with an FTP client?

(3) Any decent FTP server should have a logging facility through which you can keep track of any changes.

Answer (score 0):

As far as finding a client that could do this, it doesnt exist.  Normally people do this on the server side using something like "Filezilla Server".

As a side-note: you could write your own Java program ftp-client that would do this.  It would be less than 100 lines of code and you could distribute it to user-admins.

Also, you could write a script that uses Curl to do this, and then package the script into a .exe file so its not editable by the users.